# PYTHON How to convert string into int or float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to code a simple calculator but as a beginner I don't know how to actually convert my input strings into float or int. I want the output to be integer when it is `2` but not `2.0` while the output to be `2.5` when its a float. But I coded this and entered `1 + 1` I still get `2.0`

```
from ast import literal_eval

# User input a simple calculation
num1, operator, num2 = input('Please enter a simple math calculation ').split()
num1 = float(num1)
num2 = float(num2)

# Convert string into either int or float
def convertString1 (num1):
    val = literal_eval(num1)
    return isinstance(val, int) or (isinstance(val, float) and val.is_integer())
def convertString2 (num2):
    val = literal_eval(num2)
    return isinstance(val, int) or (isinstance(val, float) and val.is_integer())


# Condition to perform calculation and output
if operator ==  "+" :
    print("{} + {} = {}".format(num1, num2, num1+num2))
elif operator == "-" :
    print("{} - {} = {}".format(num1, num2, num1-num2))
elif operator == "*" :
    print("{} * {} = {}".format(num1, num2, num1*num2))
elif operator == "/" :
    print("{} / {} = {}".format(num1, num2, num1/num2))
else :
    print("Syntax error")
```

Comment: Because you are converting the values to float...
`num1 = float(num1)
num2 = float(num2)`. Also functions don't call themselves, you have to do that

Comment: Why have you defined functions you don't use?

Comment: You could also use `literal_eval` to parse `1` as an int but `1.0` as a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to add if statement. For example

```
if int(res) == res:
    res = int(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your numbers are displaying that way is because you're evaluating `num1` and `num2` as floats.  If you wanted to test if you have an int, you could try something like `if int(num1) == num1:` to decide if you want to apply additional formatting.  That leads into altering how it displays:

If all you're concerned with is how it displays, since you're already using `format`, try something like

```
"{:.0f}".format(a)
```

This will round the value, however, if you're sure that it's an int, then rounding it won't have any affect apart from visual.